# How to add a user to a Topic for firebase push notifications

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using push notifications and can successfully send to all devices but I want to create a page that allows users to subscribe to certain lists. Notifications will be triggered from a admin panel for the app.

I've read the documentation but I'm still new to all this so I am hoping someone might have some ideas on how to start.

Something like this: ( I am a well paid artist)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `subscribeToTopic` and `unsubscribeToTopic` methods when a user selects or deselects one of the switches.

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_messaging/lib/firebase_messaging.dart#L89

Comment: and that will be specific to that device? without having to save to a profile or something? Or is there a function to check if a user is subbed to a topic too?